# Google play meaning of installs metric

Tags: android, google-play

I admit I'm new in the android community but I search for hours and I can't find a valid well documented answer.

When viewing application in the play store(web or app) there is a metric which is in ranges called installs:

[image]

Now, I really don't care about the actual number. I do want to know on what it **based on**. I found couple of conflicted answers across the web none with reference to an actual google documentation.

The way I see it there is 3 options:

1. Plain installs - The number of times the app was installed from the store regardless to any events in the past.
2. Installs by user - The number of unique users(gmail accounts) which installed the app overtime. One install for each user.
3. Install by device - The number of unique devices which the app was installed on(It means that user could appear several times if it have more than one device or upgraded his phone etc.)

I would love to get answer with references if it's not hard because I do find conflicting opinions over the internet.

Comment: From what I can tell it seems to be depending on the **installs by user**. By the way the only documentation I found relating to that is here: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1

Answer (score 0):

In very simple terms, Its total installs from play store. If a device installs an app and uninstall from play store, the install count is decremented. And if installed again, count will be increased.

But if installed using android OS, by drag and drop to uninstall, and is not connected to internet, it cant be updated.In that case, if installed again from play store, will increment install count by one.

And of course, its total count on phone/android TV if available on android TV play store ( ** Note: ** Not all app that are on Android phone OS play store, are available on android TV os play store, EX- PUBG mobile. Dialers etc)

For, reference, this is starting point, https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/139628?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en and you can keep digging as per your time and interests. Read all answers and specially, this section on that page.

> Install-related statistics

Thanks

Comment: I know this page, it is a very detailed page about how the developer account metrics works. But it's surely not a reference to what is the number which appear on the playstore. Your answer is still a speculation, and like the other answer it's hard to believe this is just plain installs because this can be easily manipulated. I do believe it's new devices.

Answer (score -1):

> Install by device

There are less than 3 billion Android devices worldwide.

> Installs by user

There are less than 2 billion Android users worldwide.

> Plain installs

[Whatsapp](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp) has over 5 billion installs. Which can be between 5bn to 10bn but less than 10bn.

So it is obvious it is the number of total installs regardless of the other factors.
It means if you install an app on your phone, and then change your ROM to a custom ROM and then install the app again, this will count as 2 installs on the store.

Comment: I think you are right, but I ask myself: 3 billion in existence right now or 3 billion produced at some point in time?

Comment: 2.6bn is the number of active devices

Comment: From Android's twitter: https://twitter.com/Android/status/1125822326183014401

Comment: @einUsername is right. we may have 3bn active devices but how many androids which came and go during this 10 years were downloading whatsapp. So install by device seems still relevant. Plus if it was only plain installs whats is preventing me to build an army of bots installing and uninstalling my app all day long.

Comment: In fact, there really are companies which provide such service, they have thousands of devices running and you can buy traffic or install etc from them. but it's not like you can just install and uninstall on a single device. you'll need lots of devices for that. which is not profitable at all.

Comment: btw you can't build an army of bots to install an app, change the ROM, install the app again and change the ROM again. It's impractical. And also uninstalling the app will decrease the number of installs. That number is only the total number of app installs which have not been uninstalled. I'm sure they also have some kind of timeout for that if a device has not logged in for a period of time(a year for example) its data will be removed from the statistics to prevent false data from old devices.

Comment: I can live with the fact that changing to ROM is like change device. How do you know that uninstalling the app is decreasing the installs count. You can actually see it decreasing ?